# Swap file revisions in Xcode diff

Tags: xcode, diff

By any chance is there a way to swap the two files in the Xcode 4 diff so that the previous revision of a file is on the left and the current working revision on the right? By default Xcode shows the working version on the left and previous revision on the right. I'm too use to most of the Windows diff programs where it's the totally the opposite of what Xcode shows.

If not, can anyone recommend a diff program that integrates with Xcode 4?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's 2016 and it finally looks like Apple has gave us a way to do this in XCode 7.3! 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Would love an answer to your actual question--haven't been able to find anything in XCode preferences.

Sounds like maybe XCode is using FileMerge under the hood, but I didn't see anything in FileMerge's preferences about swapping the default left and right positions of files.

Personally I use P4Merge, which works well, but that doesn't work nicely for things like a "Refactor" preview inside XCode. This link has some other options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187064/graphical-diff-for-mac-os-x

Comment: It's been more than a year and I still don't have an answer to this. Still would like one.